# Column Header Styling Issue in Data Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight-2.0, wpftoolkit

I have formated the Wcf Toolkit Datagrid and below in the is the ColumnHeader Style for it
But, there are still some area in Column Header, which are not styled as shown in the image

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9aba4fbd93.jpg

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="dg:DataGridColumnHeader">   
                    <dg:DataGridHeaderBorder
                    x:Name="headerBorder"                      
                    Background="Orange">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" 
                            CornerRadius="5" 
                            Background="Orange"
                            BorderBrush="DarkOrange">                            
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding  Content}" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                                
                            </Grid>                                
                    </Border>
                    </dg:DataGridHeaderBorder>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>                 
    </Style>

 <dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" 
                 Name="dgQuestion"                      
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                 Width="740"
                 MinWidth="200"
                 MaxWidth="740"                         
                 Background="Wheat"
                 ColumnHeaderHeight="30"                       
                 ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"
                 RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"
                 CanUserAddRows="False"
                 CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                 AlternationCount="2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just found this post with the same problem and was able to fix it for me, by setting the Width to the exact width of the header (where the styling stops).

It might not work for you in your context. Also notice this is months old :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was previously having the same issue, updating to the latest version of the grid (WPFToolkit.dll) appears to have fixed this for me